# Calculate some basic operations and transform a json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-wrangling

Having a json array in this format:

```
[
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 16}
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 12}
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 10}
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 22}
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 18}
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14}
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 20}
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 8}
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14}
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 11}
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 17}
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19}
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 21}
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 9}
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 11}
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 7}
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 23}
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19}
]
```

How can I can calculate the max and the min `value` by city and day using Javascript?

For example, I have the following `value`s 16, 22 and 20 for `day: 1` and `city: "New York"` and I want to get `max: 22` and `min: 16`. Once this is calculated, I want to append these new values to all objects, no matter what the `year`, that contain `day: 1` for `city: "New York"`

```
[
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 16, max: 22, min: 16}
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 12, max: 18, min: 8}
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 10, max: 14, min: 10}
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 22, max: 22, min: 16}
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 18, max: 18, min: 8}
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14, max: 14, min: 10}
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 20, max: 22, min: 16}
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 8, max: 18, min: 8}
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14, max: 14, min: 10}
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 11, max: 21, min: 7}
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 17, max: 23, min: 9}
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19, max: 19, min: 11}
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 21, max: 21, min: 7}
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 9, max: 23, min: 9}
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 11, max: 19, min:11}
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 7, max: 21, min: 7}
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 23, max: 23, min: 9}
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19, max: 21, min: 7}
]
```

Calculating the max or the min is not a problem. I am having trouble with the structure of for loops I need to get the desired outcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to find min-max pairs for every `(day,city)` pair and then run [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to combine the aggregates with your array:

```js
let input = [
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 16},
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 12},
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 10},
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 22},
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 18},
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14},
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 20},
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 8},
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14},
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 11},
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 17},
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19},
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 21},
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 9},
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 11},
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 7},
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 23},
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19}
];

let keyFn = obj => `${obj.city}-${obj.day}`;

let minMax = input.reduce((acc,cur)=> {
   let key = keyFn(cur);
   let prev = acc[key];
   if(!prev){
      acc[key] = { min: cur.value, max: cur.value };
   } else {
      prev.min = Math.min(prev.min, cur.value);
      prev.max = Math.max(prev.max, cur.value);
   }
   return acc;
}, {});


let result = input.map(obj => ({...obj, ...minMax[keyFn(obj)]}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks! I was also wondering how I can calculate the average and the median. I think the Math operator does not work in this case, no?

Comment: @console.log median should be easier, just sort and take `length / 2` element

Comment: you mean inside minMax? Thanks!

Comment: @console.log I think it would be separate from this code - you need to gather all values for instance for `Boston` and them sort them and get middle one

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I understand the process now but I am not. sure how to put it in practice and keep min, max, median and avg together. I think I'll calculate the avg and the median out of Javascript, using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you.

```js
data =[
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 16},
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 12},
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 10},
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 22},
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 18},
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14},
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "New York", value: 20},
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "New York", value: 8},
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "New York", value: 14},
  {year: 2020, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 11},
  {year: 2020, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 17},
  {year: 2020, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19},
  {year: 2019, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 21},
  {year: 2019, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 9},
  {year: 2019, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 11},
  {year: 2018, day: 1, city: "Boston", value: 7},
  {year: 2018, day: 2, city: "Boston", value: 23},
  {year: 2018, day: 3, city: "Boston", value: 19}
]
//filter input value
var cityParam = 'New York';
var dayParam = 2;


const maxValue = data.reduce(
  (max, data) => (data.value > max  && data.city === cityParam && data.day ===dayParam ? data.value : max),
  data[0].value
);
const minValue = data.reduce(
  (max, data) => (data.value < max  && data.city === cityParam && data.day ===dayParam ? data.value : max),
  data[0].value
);
console.log(maxValue);
console.log(minValue);
```